# Convert beautifulsoup output into a dictionary

Tags: python, sql, selenium, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find a way to convert my output I got from my beautifulsoup into a dictionary. I want to use the dictionary to convert it into a pandas dataframe.
After trying several things that didn't seem to work, I am now stuck.

Can anyone help me with this issue?
My code looks like this:

```
type_effectives_dict = {
    'Immune to:':[],
    'Strongly resists:':[],
    'Resists:':[],
    'Weak to:':[],
    'Very weak to:':[]
}

# r_immune = re.compile("'Immune to:'(?:, '\w*'){1,8}")
# r_strong_res = re.compile("'Strongly resists:'(?:, '\w*'){1,8}")
# r_res = re.compile("'Resists:'(?:, '\w*'){1,8}")
# r_weak = re.compile("'Weak to:'(?:, '\w*'){1,8}")
# r_very_weak = re.compile("'Very weak to:'(?:, '\w*'){1,8}")

pokemons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='PokemonAltRow-name']")
for count, pokemon in enumerate(pokemons):
    pokemons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='PokemonAltRow-name']")
    driver.implicitly_wait(1)
    # print(pokemons[count].text)
    pokemons[count].click()
    time.sleep(1)
    page_source = driver.page_source
    time.sleep(1)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
    time.sleep(1)
    name = soup.find('h1', attrs={'data-reactid' : '.0.1.1.1'})
    # if name != None:
        # print(name.text)
    
    type_effectives = soup.find('dl', attrs={'class' : 'TypeEffectives'})
    
    type_effectives_result = re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', type_effectives.text)
    print(name.text, type_effectives_result)

                                           
    driver.back()
    driver.implicitly_wait(1)

driver.close()
```

My output:

```
Amoonguss ['Strongly resists:', 'Grass', 'Resists:', 'Electric', 'Fairy', 'Fighting', 'Water', 'Weak to:', 'Fire', 'Flying', 'Ice', 'Psychic']
Azelf ['Resists:', 'Fighting', 'Psychic', 'Weak to:', 'Bug', 'Dark', 'Ghost']
Azumarill ['Immune to:', 'Dragon', 'Resists:', 'Bug', 'Dark', 'Fighting', 'Fire', 'Ice', 'Water', 'Weak to:', 'Electric', 'Grass', 'Poison']
Bisharp ['Immune to:', 'Poison', 'Psychic', 'Resists:', 'Dark', 'Dragon', 'Flying', 'Ghost', 'Grass', 'Ice', 'Normal', 'Rock', 'Steel', 'Weak to:', 'Fire', 'Ground', 'Very weak to:', 'Fighting']
Breloom ['Resists:', 'Dark', 'Electric', 'Grass', 'Ground', 'Rock', 'Water', 'Weak to:', 'Fairy', 'Fire', 'Ice', 'Poison', 'Psychic', 'Very weak to:', 'Flying']
Chansey ['Immune to:', 'Ghost', 'Weak to:', 'Fighting']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function, you just need to send the list into the function and it will return the `list` of `dict`

```
def list_dict_conv(_list):
    dict_list = []
    for x in range(0, len(_list)):
        if ':' in _list[x]:
            key = _list[x].replace(':', '')
            dict_list.append({key: _list[x + 1]})

    return dict_list


data = list_dict_conv(_list=Amoonguss)  # give the list you want to parse
print(data)  # [{'Strongly resists': 'Grass'}, {'Resists': 'Electric'}, {'Weak to': 'Fire'}]
```